# WordPress Editor Erea very small issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wp-editor

I don't know who is the genious developer made wp editor, but I can't edit the page content because the edit box is very norrow. How can I fix this issue:
I am using:

1. Wordpress version & Theme: WordPress 5.0.2 running The WP theme.
2. Plugins :

   - WP Editor
   - WP TinyMCE Advanced

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your theme has any admin styling CSS file you can place this code at the very top.

```
.wp-block {
    max-width: 95%;
}
```

If not, you create your own admin style CSS file and override WordPress default styling.  Read Official Documentation at
[wp_enqueque_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)